# How to configure Solr to treat European English language the same as international English

Tags: solr, configuration

I'm configuring a few sites within my solution to use "European English" (`en-150` yes, it's weird, but it [is a valid culture](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-lcid/a9eac961-e77d-41a6-90a5-ce1a8b0cdb9c?redirectedfrom=MSDN)!). Does Solr treat all `en-` languages the same, or will I need to set up specific configuration files for this language?

Comment: What do you mean by "treat all en- languages the same"? How Solr stores them in index:  as a single or separate documents?

Comment: Or you are about analyzers like stopwords, stemming filters?

Comment: @x3mxray yes the latter.